VS Code loads wrong SSH credentials
I'm trying to connect to a remote server with SSH. The issue is that VS loads the wrong username (it should be nlombardi, without the prefix). Any idea how to fix this?
I tryed already to do a clean install of VS Code, deleting .vscode and Code folders.
The .ssh/config file looks good to me. I also tried to remove it but the issue is still there.
The issue started yesterday. I connected to a server, after 5 minutes I tryed to change to another one but this issue started appearing for all the servers
